# How can Oracle restrict certain data on a table to different users?

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

Searched the site and doesn't seem to find anyone had asked this question.

We have two accounts accessing the same table on the same schema/database. User_1 account was able to pull back all the records while User_2 account were only able to pull back certain data.

I am aware that Oracle has the ability to restrict table access for different users but I am not aware it can do something like this on the data level.

My question is can Oracle do this and how?

Thanks

Comment: Perhaps you create a view of non-restricted fields, and only give the lower-privileged user grants on the view.

Comment: Use a virtual private database: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/network.102/b14266/apdvpoli.htm#CHDFGBEB

Comment: fine grained access control?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can work with a view.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW V_TABLE_FOR_USER_2 AS
SELECT *
FROM THE_TABLE
WHERE {data} = {certain data};

GRANT SELECT, INSERT, DELETE, UPDATE ON THE_TABLE TO USER_1;
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, DELETE, UPDATE ON V_TABLE_FOR_USER_2 TO USER_2;
```